# Rewrite rule with .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ page.php?title=$1
```

I see that my rewriting rules are working but depends on the order of execution. If the pages rewrite rule is the first...it works only for the pages.php.

I've also "played" around with the flags but no results up there.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am missing an actual question here, so I have no clue what to answer.

Comment: With the first rule i'm trying to make the page.php links to be sitename/page.html and with the second to transform page.php?title=page-title to sitename/page-title. 

Both rules are working, but separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ page.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```